# Adding modal dialog to constructor gets rid of everything else on the page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dialog, modal-dialog

I am trying to add a basic modal dialog to pop up when I click on an image. My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<mat-card id="CARDBOX">
   <img class="logo" src="path/image.jpg" alt="image" height=25px (click)="openDialog()"/>
</mat-card>
```

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardbox',
  templateUrl: './cardbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardbox.component.scss']
})
export class CardboxComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  openDialog() {
   this.dialog.open(CardBoxComponent);
  }
}
```

When I add anything to the constructor, everything on the page is deleting, nothing shows up at all. I just want an easy way to add a pop up dialog without making a new component. What am I doing wrong and is there a way to do this?

Comment: https://dev.to/jwp/mat-dialog-in-10-minutes-4808

Answer (score 1):

Please try using it with other options as 2nd parameter.

this.dialog.open(UserProfileComponent, {
height: '400px',
width: '600px',
});

Comment: It doesn't do anything because when there is something in the constructor the whole page shows up blank.